Proving basic set equality
Prove that $(A-B)\cap C=(A\cap C)-(B\cap C)$.
I would start as follows:
suppose $x\in (A-B)\cap C$, then $x \in A$, $x \notin B$ and $x\in C$.
Here is my doubt, because I would wrongly deduce that $x \in (A \cap C)-B$.

What you want is indeed to start as you did. How would that deduction be wrong ?

What is the problem with $(A-B)\cap C \subseteq (A\cap C)-B$, which you’ve shown?

Just note that if $x \notin B$, then since $B \cap C \subseteq B$, also $x \notin B \cap C$.

That's not a wrong deduction.  And that step so far as it goes does prove that $A\cap C)-B \subseteq (A-B)\cap C$ (which is a statement that, although true, is not what was asked) but it doesn't go for enough.  The next step should be as $x\not \in B$ then $x\not \in (B\cap C)$.

"Here is my doubt, because I would wrongly deduce that x∈(A∩C)−B."
That is not a wrong conclusion.  It's a 100% true conclusion.  It's just not the conclusion you were asked to reach.  And it's a weaker conclusion than what you want.  This would be a bit akin to trying to prove "dolphins are aquatic fish-eaters" and finding early on in your proof that "dolphins are carnivores" and worrying that is a false conclusion. It's not a false conclusion.  It's a true conclusion. But you just haven't gone far enough.
Indeed if $x\in (A-B)\cap C$ then $x\in A;x\not \in B; x \in C$.  So, yes, $x \in (A\cap C)-B$ and, yes, $(A\cap C)-B \subsetneq (A-B)\cap C$. But that's only part of the way and weaker statement and not really were we want to go.
The next step is we have have to show is not just is $x\not \in B$ but $x \not \in B\cap C$.  But that's clear.  $B\cap C \subset B$ so if $x \not \in B$ we can't possibly have $x \in B\cap C$.  So $x\not \in B\cap C$ and $x\in (A\cap C)-(B\cap C)$.
That's half the problem.  Now do the other half by proving that if $x\in (A\cap C)-(B\cap C)$ the $x \in (A-B)\cap C$.  (You might also get a "weak" non-step and conclude $x \in (A-B)\cap(C-B)$.  That's also not false.)

I think you stopped at the following point:$( x \in A )$ and $( x \in C )$ and $( x \notin B )$,which implies that:
$( x \in A )$ and $( x \in C )$ and $(( x \notin B )$ or $( x \notin C ))$.
This is because, according to the logic of zero degree, the proposition $( p )$ implies the proposition $( p \vee q )$.
According to De Morgan's law, the statement:$( x \notin B )$ or $( x \notin C )$becomes the negation of the proposition:$( x \in B )$ and $( x \in C )$,and thus the negation of the proposition:$( x \in B \cap C )$.
Therefore:$( x \notin B \cap C )$.
